# How to include page number at the top right corner?

Tags: header-footer, titles

I used the code which I found here before to add numbers at the top-right corner, and they worked, except that I wanted it to start at the title page. The code that I have below only starts placing numbers at my abstract (which is supposed to be my second page since I'm following APA format). Thank you!

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
```

This is the code for my title page:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\begin{titlepage}
    \doublespacing
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{1cm}
            
        \Huge
        \textbf{Title}
            
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \LARGE
            
        \vspace{1.5cm}
            
        \textbf{Student Name}\\
        Course number\\
        Professor
            
        \Large
        University\\
        May 10, 2021
            
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try adding `\thispagestyle{fancy}` just after `\begin{titlepage}`?

Comment: @Bernard, I actually created a title page file (titlepage.tex) and inserted it using `\input {titlepage}`. When I added `\thispagestyle{fancy}` after the input command, it still didn't work. Any tips?

Comment: You should take a look at the `titling` package which defines tools to customise the `maketitle` command and the `titlepage` environment.

Comment: After \input is probably too late.  You need to put it inside the file being \input.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\thispagestyle{fancy}` inside  the `titlepage` environment.

(Although it may not be a good idea to put page numbers on a cover)

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{% normal pages
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{titlepage}
        \thispagestyle{fancy}
        \doublespacing
        \begin{center}
            \vspace*{1cm}
            
            \Huge
            \textbf{Title}
            
            \vspace{0.5cm}
            \LARGE
            
            \vspace{1.5cm}
            
            \textbf{Student Name}\\
            Course number\\
            Professor
            
            \Large
            University\\
            May 10, 2021
            
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
    
\end{document}
```